# PHP-FPM/nginx-SELinux: No input file specified

Tags: nginx, php-fpm

I have problem setting up nginx (with passenger, which works fine) with php-fpm on Fedora. When I try access index.php via browser, I get "No input file specified."

Nginx error log:

> 2013/11/29 12:50:47 [error] 2218#0: *15 FastCGI sent in stderr: "Unable to open primary script: /home/nginx/html/phptest/index.php (No such file or directory)" while reading response header from upstream, client: 109.230.17.250, server: ..., request: "GET /index.php HTTP/1.1", upstream: "fastcgi://127.0.0.1:9000", host: "..."
>   That file exists.

PHP-FPM error log shows nothing.

PHP-FPM status page works. Nginx and PHP-FPM are running under user nginx.

Nginx conf:

```
        server {
            listen 80;
            server_name ...;
            root /home/nginx/html/phptest;
            index index.php index.html index.htm;
            location ~ \.php$ {
                    include fastcgi.conf;
                    try_files $uri =404;
                    fastcgi_pass 127.0.0.1:9000;
            }
            location ~ ^/(status|ping)$ {
                 #access_log off;
                 include fastcgi.conf;
                 fastcgi_pass 127.0.0.1:9000;
            }
    }
```

PHP: doc_root is empty, open_basedir is not defined, cgi.fix_pathinfo=0
https://gist.github.com/anonymous/7705152

PHP-FPM www.conf: https://gist.github.com/anonymous/7705155

index.php file exists and is accesible from user nginx itself and from different user.

I have tried different nginx configuration and nothing helped. I guess it has something with different path handling around fastcgi, but I have no idea what to do with it.

Thanks for help.

UPDATE:
SELinux was causing this problem, now I am running it in permissive mode. Not sure how to create proper policy without causing outage.

Comment: Can you post /etc/php5/fpm/pool.d/www.conf  and /etc/php.ini please

Comment: Updated question with links.

Comment: Check to see that the file `/home/nginx/html/phptest/index.php` exists and is readable.

Comment: Yes it is. I have just disabled selinux enforcement and php file executes. I have forgot about it, because self compiled nginx (gem passenger) did not have problem with that. I have tried installing Apache and I have found following in error log: [Fri Nov 29 20:16:34.112015 2013] [suexec:notice] [pid 5447] AH01232: suEXEC mechanism enabled (wrapper: /usr/sbin/suexec)
AH00112: Warning: DocumentRoot [/home/nginx/html/phptest] does not exist

Answer (score 0):

Can you try changing your server block to this;

```
server {
    listen 80;
    server_name ...;
    root /home/nginx/html/phptest;
    index index.php index.html index.htm;
    location ~ \.php$ {
        root           /home/nginx/html/phptest;
        fastcgi_pass   127.0.0.1:9000;
        fastcgi_index  index.php;
        fastcgi_param  SCRIPT_FILENAME   $document_root$fastcgi_script_name;
        include        fastcgi_params;
    }
}
```

Comment: Did not help, same result. Same error in nginx log.

Comment: Can you try using a socket rather than 127.0.0.1:9000 - you can change this in the www.conf and also then change the fastcgi_pass to path of your socket too.